# ARKit randomly limits frame rate to 30FPS

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, frame-rate

Every once in a while when I run my ARKit project the frame rate locks to 30FPS. This seems to happen completely by random.

This happens even when the scene is empty and there are no rendering and background processes happening.

After closing Xcode and running the app again a couple times, it goes back to the default 60FPS.

Any idea what this could be?

I'm running on XCode 10.1 and iOS 12.1

Comment: This may be unhelpful given you say it works after restarting XCode, but ARKit will limit the frame rate if your battery is really low.

Comment: @Jordan Battery is full. I also made sure that low power mode is off. It seems to be completely random

Comment: Having this issue with a face tracking app... Sometimes 60fps and then a drop to 30fps... if I'm lucking it sometimes pops back up to 60fps. It seems to be completely random. I guess there my be resource things happening, but all other usage is relatively low. One thing I read is that it could be a heat thing since camera and screen are both on doing continuous work.

Comment: Yes, I also believe this to be a heat issue. The system throttles the framerate to avoid overheating.

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug for iPhone 7/8 in iOS 11/12. [Most people from forums](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/75qfbk/iphone_8_frame_rate_drops/) say that sometimes iPhone seems to get stuck at 30 fps and only restart cures its weird issue.

Also, [this bug happens](https://forum.unity.com/threads/set-arkit-pose-processing-to-30-fps.559849/) when you use Unity's building blocks for ARKit. Currently there is no explanation why this is happening. Let's wait for new updates of Xcode, ARKit and iOS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this was a while ago. But was there any update on this. I seem to be experiencing issue on the latest public Xcode version. This happens on a m1 iPad pro.

Comment: There's no official documentation describing this issue...

Comment: Ya looks like that. It seems like thermal state is the issue. Immediately when the thermal state changes to `.serious` or `.critical`. The FPS goes to 30 fps.

Answer (score 0):

Bhavin p in the comments is right.
It happens when thermal state increases.

Go to debug navigator -> click on "Energy Impact" -> scroll down and check "Thermal State"

After .serious or .critical state the FPS drop to 30